# Cannot tokenize words when using lucene SynonymFilter

Tags: java, lucene

```
public class SynonymAnalyzer extends Analyzer {


    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
        SynonymMap synonymMap = null;
        SynonymMap.Builder builder=null;
        try {
            addTo(builder,new String[]{"dns"},new String[]{"domain name system"});
            synonymMap = builder.build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream filter = new SynonymFilter(tokenizer, synonymMap, true);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }

     private void addTo(SynonymMap.Builder builder, String[] from, String[] to) {
         for (String input : from) {
             for (String output : to) {
                 builder.add(new CharsRef(input), new CharsRef(output), false);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

If I use this SynonymAnalyzer,and search for **dns is down**, query formed is **+n:domain name system +n:is +n:down**. domain name system is not tokenized as seperate tokens but I need that as seperate tokens.

Comment: It returns **domain name system** as single token. But I need it as separate tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding multi-word synonyms, you need to separate words with `SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR`:

```
addTo(builder,new String[]{"dns"},new String[]{
    "domain" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR
    + "name" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR
    + "system"});
```

(By the way, your `createComponents`, as written, will throw an NPE. Judging by what you've written, I'll assume this is an error in the example, not your code in production)

Comment: Is the reverse possible using lucene 4.10.4 ? Can I transform **domain name system** to **dns**?